# Check if contiguous date interval exists

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table in PostgreSQL which describes some events that have a start date and an end date:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  event_id serial NOT NULL,
  start_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  end_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
)
```

A single event may overlap the previous and the next one. In the following table the first 3 of 4 events form a contiguous time interval:

```
1   '2015-04-02 22:09:03'   '2015-04-02 22:19:05'
2   '2015-04-02 22:17:38'   '2015-04-02 22:27:38'
3   '2015-04-02 22:25:21'   '2015-04-02 22:36:23'
4   '2015-04-02 22:45:23'   '2015-04-02 22:55:23'
```

Is it possible to write a query that checks if a contiguous date interval between two given dates exists?

I would like to have something like:

```
select ...
from my_table
where start_date > '2015-04-02' and end_date < '2015-04-06'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, we combine intervals that overlap to find all the contiguous "islands" of the intervals:

```
with c as
  ( select *, max(end_date) over (order by start_date
                                  rows between unbounded preceding
                                           and 1 preceding)
                as previous_max
    from my_table
  )
select start_date, 
       coalesce(lead(previous_max) over (order by start_date),
                (select max(end_date) from my_table)
               ) as end_date
from c 
where previous_max < start_date 
   or previous_max is null ;
```

After that, it's easy to check if a given interval in completely surrounded by one of the found contiguous islands.

```
   with c as
  ( select *, max(end_date) over (order by start_date
                                  rows between unbounded preceding
                                           and 1 preceding)
                as previous_max
    from my_table
  ) ,
cont as
  ( select start_date, 
           coalesce(lead(previous_max) over (order by start_date),
                    (select max(end_date) from my_table)
                   ) as end_date
    from c 
    where previous_max < start_date 
       or previous_max is null  
   )
select *
from cont
where tsrange(start_date, end_date)
       @>                             -- contains
      tsrange('2015-04-02 22:10:00', '2015-04-02 22:30:00') 
limit 1 ;
```

Test at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/42844/6)

Comment: It might be cheaper to check for overlapping gaps than surrounding islands.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter. I was thinking that a recursive query would be more suitable (and efficient) when one wants to search on one range only.

Comment: Recursion comes at a price, a plain query should be faster. I updated with a query that covers all corner cases and eliminates irrelevant rows early. Maybe the OP can test the queries with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and report runtimes.

Answer (score 3):

This query returns all gaps in the data that overlap with the given time range. Also covers *leading*, *trailing* or *total* (covering) gaps:

```
WITH input(t1, t2) AS (SELECT '2015-04-02 22:00'::timestamp
                            , '2015-04-02 23:00'::timestamp)  -- t1 < t2
,    gap  AS (
   SELECT max(end_date) OVER (ORDER BY start_date
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS start_gap
        , start_date AS end_gap
        , end_date  -- for possible trailing gap
   FROM   my_table
   WHERE  end_date   >= (SELECT t1 FROM input)  -- exclude rows early
   AND    start_date <= (SELECT t2 FROM input)
   )
SELECT start_gap, end_gap
FROM   gap
WHERE  end_gap > start_gap  -- gap within time range
   OR  start_gap IS NULL AND end_gap > (SELECT t1 FROM input) -- leading gap

UNION ALL
SELECT max(end_date), NULL  -- trailing gap
FROM   gap
HAVING max(end_date) < (SELECT t2 FROM input)

UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL  -- total gap
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gap)
ORDER  BY end_gap;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hWpaoMe5)

If *nothing* is returned, the check succeeds:

> checks if a contiguous date interval between two given dates exists?

Only needs a single scan over the base table and a single window function. Should be *fast*.

If you are not familiar with window functions, read this [chapter of the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS).

Related:

- [Compare multiple date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769243/939860)

About `OVERLAPS`:

- [Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15305292/939860)

#### Function counting gaps

For a quick answer to your question without details, the query can be simplified. Also parameter handling is more convenient in a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_find_gaps(t1 timestamp, t2 timestamp)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
WITH gap AS (
   SELECT max(end_date) OVER (ORDER BY start_date
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS start_gap
        , start_date AS end_gap
        , end_date  -- for possible trailing gap & total gap
   FROM   my_table
   WHERE  end_date   >= t1  -- exclude rows early
   AND    start_date <= t2
   )
SELECT count(*)::int
     + CASE WHEN (SELECT max(end_date) >= t2 FROM gap) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
     -- covers trailing gap & total gap
FROM   gap
WHERE  end_gap > start_gap  -- gap within time range
   OR  start_gap IS NULL AND end_gap > t1  -- leading gap
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_find_gaps('2015-04-02 22:00', '2015-04-02 23:00');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hWpaoMe5)

Returns the number of gaps. `0` means, your range is covered.

Comment: Could you explain this part: `WHERE end_date >= t1 AND start_date <= t2` I understand that you want to filter out the set and it's logical, but it's not working with my data set. I have [1,10] - [10,15] - [20-23] - [28-30] and I want to find empty space for [25-27]. I'm getting empty results because where clause returns false.

Comment: @Emil: For the record, for the first query I stated: *"If nothing is returned, the check succeeds:"*. And the added function `f_find_gaps()` counts the number of gaps in the given interval. Would return *1* for your example.