# Calculate Difference in Overlapping Time in PostgreSQL / SSRS

Tags: postgresql, ssrs, gaps-and-islands, time

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2 and SSRS 3.0.  I'm trying to calculate the difference in non-overlapping time entries in a timesheet.

My data looks like this:

[image: data]

I would like this to return:

[image: results]

I can get the overlapping minutes 635, but am having trouble with the not overlapping, 605 minutes.

Comment: I see 09:35 h (575 min) of non-overlapping time, 00:30 (30 min) of overlapping time (booked more than once), 10:05 (605 min) total and 10:35 (635 min) if we count redundant ranges.

Answer (score 2):

Working with this setup:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   tbl_id     serial PRIMARY KEY
,  user_id    text NOT NULL
,  start_time timestamp NOT NULL  -- if values could be NULL ...
,  end_time   timestamp NOT NULL  -- ... it would be more complicated
);
```

### Total duration without redundancy

Your ***numbers*** indicate you just want the total duration without counting same ranges of time multiple times. Not trivial, but can be done with pure SQL rather efficiently:

```
SELECT sum(duration) AS total_duration_without_redundancy
FROM  (
   SELECT island, max(end_time) - min(start_time) AS duration
   FROM  (
      SELECT start_time, end_time
           , count(gap) OVER (ORDER BY rn) AS island
      FROM  (
         SELECT start_time, end_time
              , (start_time > max(end_time) OVER w) OR NULL AS gap
              , row_number() OVER w AS rn
         FROM   tbl
         -- WHERE  user_id = 'User1'  -- just for a given user?
         WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY start_time, end_time DESC  -- longest range 1st
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
         ) sub1
      ) sub2
   GROUP  BY island
   ) sub3;
```

**Explanation:**

- Beginning at subquery `sub1`, first order rows by `start_time`. While being at it, I actually use `ORDER BY start_time, end_time DESC` hoping to help performance a bit. But that's unimportant.
- The custom frame definition (`ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`) allows to compute the maximum `end_time` for the previous row with the window aggregate function `max()` with . If the current `start_time` is later, we have a **`gap`**.
- In `sub2` count the gaps to form islands. (All rows with the same count of gaps live on the same `island` (can be aggregated to one gap-less range).
- The rest is simple, in `sub3` compute the size of each `island` (`duration`), and get the total in the outer `SELECT`.

Related:

- [Check if contiguous date interval exists](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96974/check-if-contiguous-date-interval-exists/97007#97007)

#### Only ranges without overlap

***`non-overlapping time entries`*** like you wrote, can be interpreted in various ways. Excluding all ranges that overlap (consider only ranges of time that are covered *exactly once*) is hard to solve with pure SQL.

The special difficulty is that the "difference" of two ranges can produce two disjoint ranges if the one is a sub-range of the other, like the [Postgres manual states for range functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html):

> The union and difference operators will fail if the resulting range
> would need to contain two disjoint sub-ranges, as such a range cannot
> be represented.

I would therefore solve the problem procedurally. Iterate though rows ordered by `start_time` And compare each range to the remaining hopeful range from the last round.

This PL/pgSQL function sums all **non-overlapping time ranges** (or parts of ranges):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sum_no_overlap(OUT nol interval)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   a1 timestamp;  -- start and ...
   z1 timestamp;  -- ... end of current row
   a0 timestamp;  -- remaining candidate range ...
   z0 timestamp;  -- ... from previous row
BEGIN
   nol := '0:0';     -- init!

   FOR a1, z1 IN 
      SELECT start_time, end_time
      FROM   tbl
   -- WHERE  user_id = 'User1'             -- or just for a given user?
      ORDER  BY start_time, end_time DESC  -- better take longest range first
   LOOP
      IF    a1 >= z0 THEN               -- range starts later
      --          |a0------z0|
      --                       |a1--z1|
         nol := nol + (z0 - a0);      
         a0 := a1;
         z0 := z1;

      ELSIF a1 >= a0 AND z1 >= z0 THEN  -- range overlaps
      --          |a0------z0|
      --                 |a1--z1|
         nol := nol + (a1 - a0);
         a0 := z0;
         z0 := z1;

      ELSIF a1 >= a0 THEN               -- range included
  -- AND z1 < z0 - follows logically: 
      --          |a0------z0|
      --            |a1--z1|
         nol := nol + (a1 - a0);
         a0 := z1;  -- z0 unchaged

      ELSIF z1 <= a0 THEN               -- ignore redundant rest
      --          |a0------z0|
      -- |a1--z1|
         -- do nothing

      ELSIF z1 <= z0 THEN               -- shrink remaining rest
      --          |a0------z0|
      --       |a1--z1|
         a0 := z1;  -- z0 unchaged
         
      ELSIF z1 > z0 THEN                -- new remaining rest
      --          |a0------z0|
      --       |a1------------z1|
         a0 := z0;
         z0 := z1; -- z0 unchaged

      ELSE                              -- only for 1st iteration: a0 & z0 are NULL
         a0 := a1;  z0 := z1;
      END IF;

      RAISE NOTICE 'nol: %, a0: %, z0:%', nol, a0, z0;  -- to debug
   END LOOP;

   nol := nol + (z0 - a0);  -- rest from last row
END
$func$
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M995yDKR)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8c45e/1)</sub>

Should be fast, too, because a single scan of the table (or index) is enough.

The added ASCII art to visualize `IF` branches should help to understand.