# How to select blocks from a result by condition?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, gaps-and-islands

Example table:

```
master_id 1 created_at 22.02.1997
master_id 1 created_at 22.03.1997
master_id 1 created_at 22.04.1997
master_id 1 created_at 22.07.1997
master_id 1 created_at 22.08.1997
master_id 1 created_at 22.10.1997
```

Example query result:

```
master_id 1 date_from 22.02.1997 date_to 22.04.1997
master_id 1 date_from 22.07.1997 date_to 22.08.1997
master_id 1 date_from 22.10.1997 date_to 22.10.1997
```

*Note*: The interval between dates must not be longer than one month for a block.

Comment: Please remember to provide table definition and Postgres version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classical [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem:

```
SELECT master_id, min(created_at) AS date_from, max(created_at) AS date_to
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE step) OVER (PARTITION BY master_id ORDER BY created_at) AS range
   FROM  (
      SELECT *, created_at > lag(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY master_id ORDER BY created_at) + interval '1 month' AS step
      FROM   tbl
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
GROUP  BY master_id, range
ORDER  BY master_id, range;
```

Related (with explanation):

- [Combining separate columns into smallest possible related ranges](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228828/combining-separate-columns-into-smallest-possible-related-ranges/228840#228840)
- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)
- [Calculate Difference in Overlapping Time in PostgreSQL / SSRS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111855/calculate-difference-in-overlapping-time-in-postgresql-ssrs/111946#111946)

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me, and gave direction to study